# Exposing instance variables vs using properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am writing a public wrapper for a website. This wrapper has a lot of instance attributes, all of which are meant to be read-only.

I can't decide if it is better practice to directly expose all of the instance attributes or store them all in properties instead.

I made a `models.py` file for a bunch of classes to store information. Is it better practice to do

```py
class Profile:
    def __init__(self, account_data):
        self._account_data = account_data

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._account_data["email"]

    @property
    def avatar_url(self):
        return self._account_data["avatar_url"]

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self._account_data["username"]

    # and 10 more properties like this...
```

Or is this better?

```py
class Profile:
    def __init__(self, account_data):
        self.email = account_data["email"]
        self.avatar_url = account_data["avatar_url"]
        self.username = account_data["username"]
        # and 10 more...
```

Obviously, the second version is faster and a lot "cleaner", but what about something that plans to be a public API? Wouldn't the first be more professional? I see a lot of public APIs do the first version even when they don't really have to.

Some reasons I can think of using the first:

- Properties make the attributes read-only so they can't be accidentally tampered with.
- You can add docstrings if more information is needed about the attributes/properties.
- In certain editors like Pycharm, all properties are organized together when accessing an object's attributes, so they don't get mixed up with private instance variables (that start with an _) and other stuff, which is helpful when using a public API.

Or should I do a mix of both, only using properties when more "advanced" computation has to be done to get the attribute?

Thanks!

Comment: I like option 2. Properties just slow things down. You hand them a rope, if they end up swinging from the rafters, its on them.

Comment: Option 2 is *good*. Although with option 1, there's more clarity as to what is coming in as `account_data`. and you have separate properties for each functionality. but again option 2 is the easy way I would say (go-to way).

Comment: Not that this is opinion or anything... when I see a zillion properties and type annotations for everything, one thing is clear. This person really didn't want to program in python in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using some kind of framework like Django that already has its own model class, I suggest using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), which are built-in to the standard library as of Python 3.7.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Profile:
    email: str
    avatar_url: str
    username: str

foo = Profile(email="foo@example.com", avatar_url="https://example.com", username="foo")
```

By using `frozen=True`, you'll get an error if you try to modify any property as follows:

```
foo.email = "DANGER"                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FrozenInstanceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d7ece3014ce6> in <module>
----> 1 foo.email = "DANGER"

<string> in __setattr__(self, name, value)

FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'email'
```